# HTML table has random spacing

Tags: html, html-table, spacing

For some reason my tables have huge gaps between the rows and I'm not sure why. I've set the padding and spacing to 0...

> table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="460" border="0"

... but there are huge gaps between the lines of text. Any ideas why this should be? Here's a sample of the table...

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="460" border="0">
            <tr>
              <td width="12" rowspan="17"><img src="images/z_spacer.gif" width="10"       height="10" /></td>
              <td height="30" colspan="2" align="left" valign="top"><p  class="heading">A date with...<br />
              </p></td>
              <td width="20" rowspan="17"><img src="images/z_spacer.gif" width="10"   height="10" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="106" height="20" align="left" valign="top"><p   class="bodybold">What?</p></td>
              <td width="322" height="20" align="left" valign="top"><p class="body">Monday Morning Meeting<img src="images/z_spacer.gif" alt="" width="10" height="10" /></p></td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

And I have some CSS code too...

```
table {
border: 0 solid #FFFFFF;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr,td {
border: 0 solid #FFFFFF;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I dont see any "random" spacing. http://jsfiddle.net/CZMN6/ The width="460" is what is making the width span all the way across. Also, it is highly unrecommended to use inline styles

Comment: Yeah so it's the spacing above and below the text. The table goes on for a while and without any borders it's just too much space in between each line. I want the rows to push up closer to each other. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra spaces are the margins on the content. Try adding the following style to the style sheet

```
td * { margin: 0px; }
```

This will collapse the margins of the content. Adjust the value to make more space if needed.